# integer variable expression in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to use integer expression in `docker-compose.yml` to set ports based on the `BASE_PORT` variable.

**I have a `.env` file with the following content:**

```
BASE_PORT=57900
```

**My start bash script looks like this:**

```
#/bin/sh

. .env
docker-compose stop
docker-compose rm -v -f
docker-compose up -d adminserver
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
...
services:
  adminserver:
    image: ....
    hostname: ...
    ports:
      - ${BASE_PORT}:8001
    ...
```

This configuration works like a charm, `docker ps | grep 8001` returns with a proper content.

**But I would like to use more port configurations and more `ports` sections:**

```
...
services:
  adminserver:
    image: ....
    hostname: ...
    ports:
      - $((BASE_PORT+1)):8001
      - $((BASE_PORT+2)):8002
      - $((BASE_PORT+3)):8003
    ...

  databaseserver:
    image: ....
    hostname: ...
    ports:
      - $((BASE_PORT+10)):1541

  zookeeper:
    image: ....
    hostname: ...
    ports:
      - $((BASE_PORT+30)):2181

  kafka:
    image: ....
    hostname: ...
    ports:
      - $((BASE_PORT+40)):9092
      - $((BASE_PORT+41)):9093
      - $((BASE_PORT+42)):9094
```

The `$((BASE_PORT+1))` expression works in shell but it does not work in my *.yml file.

I get this error back:

```
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "ports" option in service "adminserver": "$((BASE_PORT+1)):8001"
```

Any idea how to make it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker Compose just doesn't support that.

In your example you have a range of contiguous ports on both the host and container side.  [The `ports:` syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) *does* support this mode:

```
ports:
  - '10000-10003:8000-8003'
```

There is still no expression parser or math capability, but you could write

```
ports:

  - '${BASE_PORT}-${FINAL_PORT}:8000-8003'
```

and that would be closer to what you need.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer because It is a proper answer to my question. But what to do if I have multiply ports section (that is my case, I edited my post)?

Answer (score 3):

if u want '10000-10003:8000-8003'

try set:

```
BASE_PORT_PREFIX=1000
```

then:

```
ports:
      - ${BASE_PORT_PREFIX}0:8000
      - ${BASE_PORT_PREFIX}1:8001
      - ${BASE_PORT_PREFIX}2:8002
      - ${BASE_PORT_PREFIX}3:8003
```

this works not only in port-range, but everywhere besides .env, yaml...